# UFW does not block meterpreter

Tags: linux, firewalls, wordpress, reverse-shell

I am doing some pen testing on my wordpress server. I wanted to see what would happen if the attacker were to get a hold of my username and password for wordpress.

So I used the standard exploit in msfconsole wp_admin_shell_upload and set password and username.

What I do not understand is why my UFW does not block the established connection. ( My rules are set to block everything apart from port: 21,80 & 22)

But I can see a connection established on port 48846. Why is this not blocked and why am I able to send commands to remote machine via meterpreter and receive data?

Screenshots below:

Client:
[image: Client]

Attacker:
[image: Attacker]

Answer (score 3):

The connection of the reverse shell originates at the attacked system, i.e. it is an outgoing connection. You ufw rules only restrict incoming connections but allow arbitrary outgoing connections - and thus allow the reverse shell.

Comment: But it still must block the commands from meterpreter since those are either way incoming.

Comment: Or do you mean once you established an outgoing connection to attacker, communication can happen both ways?

Comment: The connection is established. The content within that connection is not blocked because that's not the type of firewall you have. Every connection has data travelling both ways.

Comment: @Linux: It is perfectly normal in a connection that data are exchanged in both directions. What these data mean (i.e. command or response) does not depend on how the connection was established, i.e. it might be that the target of the connection ("server") send the command and the origin of the connection (client) executes the command and sends the response.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I see, are there any ways I can prevent this scenario from happening whilst being able to run a server? Would it be wise to lock down all outgoing as well apart from ssh & http port?

Comment: @Linux: Sure you could block all outgoing traffic. But this might impact the functionality of your server, i.e. no way to get automatic updates, no way to send mail etc. Anyway, your original question asked for an explanation why it is this way and this question is answered. Asking for improvements to your setup is a new question which also needs more details about the use case.

Answer (score -2):

I think that "ufw deny to eth0 from any"  might do the trick but I haven't tested.  It might completely isolate the box from the network or it might block any incoming connections from going back out.  I'd guess that it depends what the box is being used for.

Comment: This would do nothing to block outgoing connections...